# App crashes while trying to push a new view controller from web view delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a `UINavigationController` that contains a `UIViewController` (say 'FirstVC'). This 'FirstVC' contains a `UIScrollView` and on each page of this `UIScrollView` I have added another `UIViewCotroller` (say 'SecondVC'). This **SecondVC** contains a `UIWebView` that has several links. I want to push another `UIViewController` (say 'ThirdVC') having a `UIScrollView` on it. but when I try to do the same it crashes my applicatoin. 
Here is code I have applied:

**FirstVC**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ShowThirdVCNotification:) name:@"ShowThirdVC" object:nil]; 

}

-(void)showAlbumNotification:(id)notificationObject{
    NSLog(@"ShowThirdVCNotification: %@", [notificationObject object]);// It's an array

    ThirdVC *controller = [[ThirdVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdVC" bundle:nil];
    [controller setImageArr:[notificationObject object]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
}
```

/* SecondVC.view gets added to the scrollView of FirstVC when it loads */

**SecondVC**:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [request URL]];

    if ([[urlStr lastPathComponent] rangeOfString:@".jpg"].length) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShowAlbum" object:self.imageDetailArr];
        return NO;
    }
return YES;
}
```

**On Thread 1 it lists followings:**

```
4   0x00b0a8ab in -[UIWebScrollView didMoveToWindow] ()
5   0x007a583e in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
6   0x007af6d1 in -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
7   0x007a54bb in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
8   0x007a54bb in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
9   0x007a54bb in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
10  0x007af6d1 in -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
11  0x007a54bb in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
12  0x007a54bb in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
13  0x007a1c72 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] ()
14  0x007a04c6 in __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview ()
15  0x007a0141 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] ()
16  0x009e69bb in -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] ()
17  0x009e6c86 in -[UINavigationTransitionView _navigationTransitionDidStop] ()
18  0x0079a499 in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] ()
19  0x00799d6d in +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] ()
20  0x007a326c in +[UIView(Animation) commitAnimations] ()
21  0x009e6702 in -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] ()
22  0x009e5ccb in -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] ()
23  0x008422b7 in -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] ()
24  0x008423df in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] ()
25  0x00842561 in -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] ()
26  0x0095e4ca in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] ()
27  0x007a8301 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
```

Comment: What does it say in the log when it crashes?

Comment: There is nothing printed on the log but Thread 1 lists following:

#4 0x00b0a8ab in -[UIWebScrollView didMoveToWindow] ()
#5 0x007a583e in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#6 0x007af6d1 in -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#7 0x007a54bb in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#8 0x007a54bb in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#9 0x007a54bb in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#10 0x007af6d1 in -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()

and more

Comment: I can't understand if it's related to UIView hierarchy or something else.. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use `UIWebViewNavigationType` condition and solve your problem
Try this:-

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
        NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [request URL]];

        if ([[urlStr lastPathComponent] rangeOfString:@".jpg"].length) {

            if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
            {
                ThirdVC *controller = [[ThirdVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdVC" bundle:nil];
                controller setImageArr:self.imageDetailArr];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];

            }
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response elppa. but it's not possible to push a view controller from SecondVC (it is delegated to UIWebViewDelegate) as secondVC.view is added as a subview on FirstVC.view. That's why I used Notification to push it on FirstVC.